# Are there any tools out there that measure Angular unit test coverage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm looking to see if there are any tools available to see how much of a code base is covered in unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of frameworks/libraries nowadays for running/doing tests, but if you are using AngularJS you're probably testing with a combination of [Mocha](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) and [Jasmine](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine).

In any case you can achieve what you want by using [coveralls](https://coveralls.io/). Just to get you an idea, this is something similar to what you would get:

[image]

**NOTE:** Just in case you are interested, I'm using this [generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angularjs-module). It will give you a "nice" setup/skeleton from the beginning; as always, you can tune the project structure and everything else later.

Answer (score 0):

If you started your Angular app from a generator that uses the Karma test runner, such as [generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular), then install [karma-coverage](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage) to generate code coverage reports.